# AD Domain joined linux server equivalent of NLA

Tags: linux, active-directory, ssh

First, some background.

Today, if you're in a mostly-Windows Server AD environment with just a small number of linux servers, you have a choice for authenticating to the servers via SSH:

1. Manage the linux servers over SSH with certificate authentication (the normal linux way)
2. Join the linux servers to your AD domain (realm+sssd) and manage them over SSH with username/password authentication

The problem is option 1 leaves admins to manage a separate set of credentials from the rest of the environment, and option 2 has admins providing passwords directly to the remote servers over the network before machines have fully identified each other.

In the Windows world, this is solved (for RDP, at least, which I know should be avoided) via Network Level Authentication. A simplified version of the process looks like this:

1. The user starts to connect to the remote computer
2. The remote computer responds with AD computer account token
3. Local computer validates the token, sees NLA support, and shows a credential dialog to the user
4. User completes the dialog with credentials
5. Local computer validates credentials with the domain control (not the remote computer)
6. The DC provides the local computer with an authentication token
7. The local computer presents the token to the remote computer
8. The remote computer validates the token against the domain
9. On success, the user is permitted to access the remote computer.

Actually, the process can be even simpler, where the existing auth token created for the user when they first logged in to the local computer can already be used.

This is a complex process, and I've certainly made errors describing it. The point is the authentication token takes the place of the certificate from the linux story, such that the user never provides actual credentials to a potentially unknown machine. Moreover, the reliance by all parties on the trusted DC makes things even better than the linux story, because the user isn't left to manage their own certificates, even through their own software (rather it's software provided for them).

---

Now for the question. Is there a way to get something similar for authenticating an SSH session to an AD-joined linux server, where the server never sees the user credentials but the user experience is still the Windows-native credential validation?

Comment: NLA is derived from an authentication mechanism (Kerberos) used for a long time on Unix and Linux systems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a lot to address, but essentially what is needed is a "kerberized" SSH or whatever. NLA also provides an additional step (not specified here) of not providing a console session (which is expensive resource-wise to create) until the authentication is validated.

More to the point, aside from the complexities, which are prohibitive, I don't see a huge interest in this because there's already a workaround. Use a bastion jump host to front end the Linux hosts, disallowing the type of access/port(s) from others. That bastion host can be Windows and support all the features that are missing.

Bastion jump hosts are also becoming more common in AD environments for allowing types of access such as RDP  to protected resources.

Also for the RDP example, the credentials aren't actually protected from the server. That is addressed by using the /RemoteGuard switch.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/identity-protection/remote-credential-guard

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/mstsc